# How to add badges in navigation bar i.e. number label on icon in xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin

Adding badges in navigation bar using xamarin.forms.  I tried using the custom renderer , but failed to inflate the menu in native android since i am not getting the OncreateoptionsMenu() in the renderer.But, is there any solution to add the badges in xamarin.forms?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to hide the Navigation bar in your page
`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(YOUR_PAGE, false);`

and then create a custom navigation bar with stackLayout with your badges.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty workaround is to create a set of icon with the badge number, which involves least hack and you may still use the same navigation bar.

For example:

> [image]
>   [image]